# Vs code console closing faster than lightning, how do i keep it open

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Hello guys i am new to programming and i just installed vs code, everything is working fine except when i run the code the console comes and goes without me even seeing the output.So how do i make it stay. or how do i run the output inside the vs code terminal and just eliminate that pop up console.

The thing is i need to take screenshots of the output for my lecturer to see for future projects. Attached is a screenshot.[the console is only here because it needs input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HA04T.png)[here after input it just disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOJt2.png)

Comment: use the internal terminal or add `scanf` call at the end of your program

Comment: thats what i was asking, how do i activate the internal terminal, like the steps

Comment: read up in the docs about `launch.json` on the debug pages, it is called `integrated terminal`, the same can be done with tasks